# Angular not subscribing to SignalR message

Tags: angular, azure, signalr, azure-functions

I'm trying to subscribe to the message I sent, but it keep returning null in the browser

[image]

The SignalR connection is already established and I can send messages, but it's not subscribing to any changes. Why is that?

SignalR Service

```js
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";
import { SignalViewModel } from "./signal-view-model";
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SignalRService {
  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;
  signalReceived = new EventEmitter<SignalViewModel>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.buildConnection();
    this.startConnection();
  }

  private buildConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://localhost:7070/api")
      .build();
  }
  sendMessage(message: SignalViewModel) {

    this.http.post('http://localhost:7070/api/messages', message).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
  private startConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Connection Started...");
        this.registerSignalEvents();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error while starting connection: " + err);

        //if you get error try to start connection again after 3 seconds.
        setTimeout(function () {
          this.startConnection();
        }, 3000);
      });
  }

  private registerSignalEvents() {
    this.hubConnection.on("SignalMessageReceived", (data: SignalViewModel) => {
      this.signalReceived.emit(data);
    });
  }
}
```

SignalViewModel

```js
export class SignalViewModel {
  clientuniqueid: string;
  type: string;
  message: string;
  date: Date;
}
```

component

```js
  notificationSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {

 this.signalRService.signalReceived.subscribe(msg => {
      this.messages.push(msg);
      console.log(this.messages)

    });

//I also tried it like the following, but same issue

 this.notificationSubscription = this.signalRService.signalReceived.subscribe(msg => {
      this.messages.push(msg);
      console.log(this.messages)

    })

...
```

How can I get it to subscribe successfully? I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this approach. On the signalR service create an EventEmitter:

```js
@Output() onSignalRMessage: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

And call the private function to receive data as `SignalViewModel`.

```js
private registerSignalEvents() {
    this.hubConnection.on("SignalMessageReceived", (data: SignalViewModel) => {
      this.newMessage(data as SignalViewModel);
    });
  }

private newMessage(data: SignalViewModel) {
    this.onSignalRMessage.emit(data);
  }
```

Then on the component:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  /** Invoked when is received new data*/
  this.signalRService.onSignalRMessage.subscribe((data: SignalViewModel) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

And don't forget add the `signalRService` to the constructor.

Update1: After running your code, I can successfully connect to my local signalR service and also to the Azure SignalR Service and I'm receiveing data. As you can see the problem is not connecting and not with the received data.

[image: Console logs]

You should see what is wrong with the Azure functions.

Also I would recommend to change your client side SignalR package from `@aspnet/signalr` that is now obsolete to the new `@microsoft/signalr` package.

Comment: I assume ```onNotification``` is supposed to be ```onSignalRMessage``` I added this    this.signalRService.onSignalRMessage.subscribe((data: SignalViewModel) => {
      console.log("SIGNALR DATA", data)
    }); but it never shows up in output

Comment: Ok, did it shows on the service? put that console.log on the registerSignalEvents`.

Comment: It didn't show up if I move it to service either. If I have no console.log and I send a message then I get this in the console https://postimg.cc/3y09MXMQ . I feel like it's giving me the impression that the connection isn't established, but then it wouldn't be showing this https://postimg.cc/VddffFPJ so I'm confused lol

Comment: postimg.cc/VddffFPJ this means that it is successfully connected. The last test you can do is remove the `SignalViewModel` cast and see again the console.log. `this.hubConnection.on("SignalMessageReceived", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });`

Comment: nope. same issue. Also I'm using the http.post way from my original question to send the message to the service. I noticed the private newMessage method from your answer so that's why I mentioned it. I'm not using that to send new message

Comment: So you can see that is nothing to do with the event emiter and the subscriber. You receiving null data. Can you upload the code to github and share it with me so I can help you?

Comment: ok done. I also sent you an email with some additional info too. Thanks! Just submit a bid to use signalr service. Bid is being placed from listing-card.component.ts confirmBid method

Comment: @Kiril1512 Could you please take a look at this question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72776033/signalr-the-new-message-does-not-shows-in-target-clients-message-box-angular

Answer (score 2):

You have to use obsarvable, in your case you will have something like this:

In your service:

```
  import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

  // In your declaration
  private source = new BehaviorSubject();
  signalReceived = this.source.asObservable();

  private registerSignalEvents() {
    this.hubConnection.on("SignalMessageReceived", (data: SignalViewModel) => {
      this.source.next(data)
    });
  }
```

in your component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.signalRService.signalReceived.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
 }
```

Comment: I added the code to the service and component, but I still get ```null``` returned

Comment: EventEmitter are used to communicate between parent and child components not in the service. if you want to share data between service and component you have to use observables.

Comment: I added the code to the service, but ```private source = new BehaviorSubject();``` doesn't work without adding a parameter so I added null in the declaration. It was saying ```Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.``` I thought this would translate to a value after subscribing to a change, but I'm still getting null from subscribe when I send a new message. I changed the ngOnInit line to the one in your answer too. Updated signalr service: https://pastebin.com/ejL3KuyW Any ideas why I'm still getting null?

Comment: befaore this.source.next(data) in registerSignalEvents try to log data. what is the result ?

Comment: I added the following line ```console.log("DATA OUTPUT", data)``` right before ```this.source.next(data)``` inside ```registerSignalEvents()``` ,but when I send a message from the component, the console never outputs DATA OUTPUT at all. It's missing from output

Comment: I also tried adding a couple alerts to see if they get outputted. The one before this.hubConnection is the only one that does. Reference: https://pastebin.com/J1p4cu1P    Any ideas?

Comment: So you never receive "SignalMessageReceived" event. but registerSignalEvents is called

Comment: If I log out of my application, refresh the page and log back in. on login, the alert called ```alert("THIS ALERT OUTPUTS")``` outputs. The second alert never outputs though. I never see ```alert("THIS ALERT DOESN'T OUTPUT")``` come up on the screen

Comment: Is the reason I'm having issues because I'm using azure functions so it's not a constant connection to my backend? It does say websocket connected though in the browser when I login: https://postimg.cc/VddffFPJ   I would think the websocket is tied to the hubConnection instance so it would just work, but maybe it's because I'm using azure functions...

Comment: have a look at this sample https://github.com/atverma/AKS-Angular-AspnetCore-SQLServer/blob/ea9afcd8db984be2a68fe37e2ef6d17da9225eba/sampleangularapp/src/app/home/home.component.ts