# SignalR not subscribing inside Angular service

Tags: angular, signalr, azure-functions

I have my SignalR Angular service hooked up to the backend fine. When I log into my application, I get my access_token. I can also send messages and subscribe to the message I just sent, but I can't subscribe to it via SignalR. If I have two browsers open and I send the message via one browser. The portal signalr service message count goes up by one and the subscribe method from this line

```
 this.http.post('http://localhost:7070/api/messages', message).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

returns the new message via the console.log inside that subscribe.
[image: ![enter image description here]

But for some reason I can't receive the message via service.

Currently if I assign `test` as BehaviorSubject value:

`private source = new BehaviorSubject("test");`

then this line in ngOnInit inside component outputs

```
this.signalRService.signalReceived.subscribe(data => console.log("Output:", data))
```

[image]

It never returns the newly subscribed message. Not that I would expect it to since the message isn't even coming into the service.

Although it's also worth noting I can't initialize test to it at the same time. It was more for demonstration

[image]

so if it's initialized as `private source = new BehaviorSubject(null);`
component console output is `Output: null`

How can I get the SignalR service to return the value? It's using the azure function code from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-azure-functions-javascript) and it's able to connect no problem to the sample chat app in that article as well.

[image]

It can receive messages between 2 different browsers too via sample app so I think it's related to the client more than the backend given that this test works. I've been stuck on this for awhile so I appreciate any help!

signalr service

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, Output } from "@angular/core";
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";
import { SignalViewModel } from "./signal-view-model";
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})

export class SignalRService implements OnDestroy {
  @Output() onSignalRMessage: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;
  private source = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  signalReceived = this.source.asObservable();
  destroy = new Subject();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.buildConnection();
    this.startConnection();
  }

  private buildConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://localhost:7070/api")
      .build();
  }

  sendMessage(message: SignalViewModel) {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:7070/api/messages', message).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }

  private startConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Connection Started...");
        this.registerSignalEvents();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error while starting connection: " + err);

        //if you get error try to start connection again after 3 seconds.
        setTimeout(function () {
          this.startConnection();
        }, 3000);
      });
  }

  private registerSignalEvents() {
    this.hubConnection.on("SignalMessageReceived", (data: SignalViewModel) => {
      this.source.next(data)
    });
  }

  private newMessage(data: SignalViewModel) {
    this.onSignalRMessage.emit(data);
  }


  getSignalReceived() {
    return this.signalReceived;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy.next();
    this.destroy.complete();
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your component code?  It sounds like you may be getting a different instance of the service when you are injecting it.

Comment: I don't think it's the component that is the issue. If I put a ```console.log(data)``` right above the ```this.source.next(data)```  inside signalr service method ```private registerSignalEvents()``` then it never outputs. If I open a different browser and place a bid in the first browser with the console.log in the service then I never see that in the second browser.

Comment: Reading it over again, I don't think there is an issue with it either.  I thought you may be providing a separate instance of the service, but if you were you would probably be getting double the values since each service would be listening to and responding to the events.

Comment: Correct.  Can't retrieve the new message any other way at this time except from http.post subscribe for some reason. So only the same instance that sent the message can see the message technically

Comment: Did you try using `EventEmitter`?

Comment: EventEmitter doesn't output anything at all in the console. But before worrying about EventEmitter, wouldn't it make more sense to see why it doesn't come in service to begin with?

Comment: the issue was is the place you initialize the this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder() . use app.component to initialize and try it again .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using code from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62578942/4350389) from a different post I made and I didn't realize the observable answer changed the topic name or whatever. Not sure why the EventEmitter way didn't work, but once I adjusted it to `newMessage` it started working.

```
 private registerSignalEvents() {
    this.hubConnection.on("SignalMessageReceived", (data: SignalViewModel) => {
      this.source.next(data)
    });
```

to

```
  private registerSignalEvents() {
    this.hubConnection.on("NewMessage", (data: SignalViewModel) => {
      this.source.next(data)
    });
```